# Mangle public variable names with UglifyJS

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs

I have code similar to this:

```
(function (global) {
    var MyObject = function (arg1, arg2) {
        this.publicVar = arg1;
        this._internalVar = arg2;
    };
    MyObject.prototype = {
        publicFunc: function (param) {
            return param + this._internalVar;
        }
    };
    global.MyObject = MyObject;
}(window));
```

Can I somehow get UgilfyJS to mangle `_internalVar` because it is not intended to be used outside of this scope? I know it can be done with closure compiler using advanced compression etc but I'm using anvil to build and uglifyjs to minify.

Comment: accessing ( new window.MyObject() )._internalVar is your issue ?

Comment: @rad I find it's useful for internal objects which will not be minified by default.

Answer (score 2):

To protect _internalVar , I tried

```
(function (global) {

    var MyObject = function () {};

    MyObject.prototype = (function(){     

        var _internalVar = 2;        

        return {
             publicVar: 1,             
             publicFunc: function (param) {
                return param +' '+ _internalVar;
            }
        };

    })();

    global.MyObject  = MyObject;

}(window));
```

and tried to access

```
console.log(  ( new window.MyObject()).publicVar  );
```

which print **1**

```
console.log(  ( new window.MyObject())._internalVar  );
```

which is `undefined`

```
console.log( ( new window.MyObject()).publicFunc('value') );
```

which print **value 2**

for more information please check http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript

Comment: In this implementation all instances of MyObject share the same `_internalVar`, I want each instance to have its own value. But of course, I want all instances to share prototype.